# I can't find the jenkins password to unlock the website

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to install Jenkins, but, in one part I need to unlock Jenkins, and I didn't find the file with the password, it doesn't exist on my pc. I tried to run this command on my terminal (Windows):

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

But this is the result: (I'm running the terminal as Administrator)

[image]

So what do I do now?

Comment: It should be in your home directoty, in [.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611411/initialadminpassword-file-is-not-created-in-jenkins-folder-in-windows-10-os). It should also ne referenced in the jenkins.log, if you can find that (probably in .jenkins/logs). Can't explain "unable to access..". Is it in system32?  Cd to.location or use dull path to war.

Comment: that error message is not a password problem but the java command not finding the jenkins war file.  Make sure you run the command in the folder where that file is located on your PC

Comment: I highly recommend you use the docker container for Jenkins. It has great documentation https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker

Comment: If you not found the code as mentioned your folder go to Jenkins.err and then you see many lines as well as code...

Answer (score 1):

Try finding this file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword

Answer (score 0):

If you unable to find the the Initial password folder, then follow the below steps.

1. Install git bash on our system.
2. Open git bash
3. check your working directory and move to `C:\Program Files\Jenkins.`
4. Do `ls` command and  you will see the `jenkins.war` folder.
5. execute the command `java jar jenkins.war`
6. Now do `ls` , you can see the `jenkins.err.log` file.
7. Do `cat jenkins.err.log` -- Now you can see the password within it copy it and post it on jenkins login.